# Can it harm to just store the user in session instead of using forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

in past projects I've always worked with `Forms authentication.`

Now in this project, a custom authentication implementation  is built.

It's very simple: when you log on (with a logon form, and the credentials are positively tested against the database) your `userid` is stored in session.

Then, in a custom `AuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute`, a check is done wether there is a userid in session. If there is: you are authenticated (allowed to visit the page) and if there is not: you are redirected to the logon page.

My gut says this sounds to simple to be good, but to be honoust I can not find a reason forms authentication is better than this implementation.

Do you know any reason?

Comment: I implemented this type of authenticating long time ago and I think this is far better than the Form authentication. I see you've accepted the answer that said sessions don't encrypt cookies. Although he is right, but I'm thinking whats the point of encrypting the cookies? If someone could sniff my cookie, whether encrypted or not, he can create a request and put that encrypted sessionid in his request and just like that can creep into my account. That's why the SSL and HTTPS plays a major role to protect users credentials. Am I wrong about that or not considering something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use Session for Authentication or any security for that matter.

As I mentioned in my comments to Chris,

Sessions by default do not use an encrypted cookie. That means that the session id is sent in plain text. This is Easy to sniff, and anyone can grab that id, and impersonate another user on non-ssl connections.

Even if you use an encrypted session cookie Sessions are "volatile" while auth tickets are not. IIS will kill sessions whenever it feels like it, even in the middle of doing something on the site, IIS can just kill your session and you will now be logged out for no apparent reason.   IIS kill sessions when it needs to clean up memory, when the worker process is recycled, when exceptions are thrown and uncaught, and pretty much whenever IIS decides it wants to.  You don't want users "logged in" status dependent upon IIS's whim.

This doesn't even get into issues with server farms... which are just best avoided... yes, you can share session state in server farms, but it's best to avoid this as it's a huge performance bottleneck.

Finally... WHY?  IIS has a complete, and bone simple way to do auth built-in.  Just one call to FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie and IIS takes care of all the security for you... you're already using Authorize Attributes, so why create the custom ones?  This just doesn't even make any sense.

It's like someone saying "I know that Locks are a well respected and well tested way to secure doors, but I prefer to use my custom noodle approach".

Comment: The 'This just doesn't even make any sense.' is exactly what I was thinking when I looked at the code, just as Chris' remark 'don't implement your own authentication'. But these guys are, how should I say it, somewhat cocky, and they think this is a good solution.

Comment: Pride goeth before the fall. The greatest secret in the programming world is that none of us know what the hell we're doing. We just try to apply our knowledge and experience to produce the best solutions possible at the time. If you think you know it all and won't accept criticism, then you're a dinosaur, and we all know what happened to them.

Comment: @Michel - You actually have to go out of your way and write a lot of extra code to do it yourself.  So yeah, it doesn't make sense.  At least they're using an AuthorizationFilter approach, which is better than an ActionFilter or trying to use some other event further down the pipeline.    Simply put, if you're not using an IIdentity/IPrincipal based authentication with .NET, you are probably doing it very wrong.  ASP.NET Identity doesn't use FormsAuthentication, but it does use IIdentity/IPrincipal, and I've implemented custom IIdentity/IPrincipal implementations before.

Comment: @Michel - Some people don't understand how the pipeline works, and they don't understand how FormsAuth ando/or Identity works, so they don't know how they can be extended.  So when they have a need that isn't covered, they go off and implement a totally custom solution which more often than not is insecure.

Answer (score 4):

Functionally, there's actually not much difference. With Forms Auth, an encrypted value (the ticket) is sent to the client as a cookie. On each subsequent request, the client sends the cookie back to the server, Forms Auth decrypts the ticket and attempts to find a matching user. If it succeeds, the client is treated as "logged in", while if it fails, the client is sent to the login page to re-authenticate.

In your situation, you set the user id in the session, which sends an encrypted value representing the session id to client as a cookie. On each subsequent request, the client sends the cookie back the server, where the session is looked up and restored. If the session is restored successfully, the user id will be present, and the client will be treated as "logged in". If the session cannot be restored, then there's no user id and the client will be sent to the login page to re-authenticate.

Forms Auth works independently of Session, so you can choose to not use sessions in your application, but still use Forms Auth. However, everything it does could easily be handled just as well by the Session.

One big difference is going to be in attack vectors. With your solution, if a malicious entity gained access to your database or were able to use SQL injection, they could rather easily create themselves a session that would make them appear "logged in". One good step in limiting this would be to not just check for a user id, but also check that the user id actually resolves to a valid user. However, even then, the id of a valid user could probably be easily guessed at random, especially if you're using an auto-incrementing primary key.

With Forms Auth on the other hand, there's no way to present a valid encrypted value to the server representing a user without access to the machine key of the server. This is a much more challenging attack vector, requiring actual penetration of the server.

All that said, the biggest difference is that your solution brought you here, to ask how good it actually is. Microsoft has security experts with decades of experience working on their authentication solutions. Due to the large install-base of their products, malicious entities target their authentication schemes all the time, providing hardening. You only know how good your wall is if someone knocks it down. Until that happens, you just hope it can withstand attack. But, after it gets knocked down, you learn *how* it got knocked down, and can then build a new wall without that defect. This is what Microsoft has been doing for decades: building new walls with less defects each time. You don't have that experience, and your solution has not been tested in such a way. That means your solution, any solution you build, whether it looks for a user id or not, will always be deficient to Forms Auth and other built in forms of authentication. This is why seasoned developers universally say *don't implement your own authentication*, and I'll join in the chorus: don't implement your own authentication.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  They are not similar, much less "not much different".  First, sessions by default are not encrypted.  That means that the session id is sent in plain text.  Easy to sniff, and anyone can grab that id, and impersonate another user on non-ssl connections.  Second, even if you use an encrypted session cookie Sessions are "volatile" while auth tickets are not.  IIS will kill sessions whenever it feels like, even in the middle of doing something on the site, IIS can just kill your session and you will now be logged out for no apparent reason.

Comment: The same applies to the auth ticket. You can just as easily sniff that and present yourself as a logged in user. The fact that it's encrypted doesn't matter from a client-side penetration standpoint. The encryption only prevents creating your own tickets at will.

Comment: You're correct, and that's was actually thinking.  Someone can just try different session ID's, which can be even worse if you have a predictable session ID vulnerability.   And it makes you vulnerable to session fixation attacks.

Comment: @Erik: you say ' IIS will kill sessions whenever it feels like, even in the middle of doing something on the site, IIS can just kill your session and you will now be logged out for no apparent reason'. doesn't the .NET framework use the session framework for remembering which authentication id's are valid and which are not?

Comment: @Michel - No.  Authentication is entirely managed by the authentication ticket.  You don't even have to have session enabled to use authentication.

Comment: @Erik thanks, I thought session state was needed also. So that's another step to a session-free product.